# How to handle Sketch exported SVG with ids

Tags: html, css, svg, sketchapp

I want to use svg icons in my page. The designers I work with use Sketch to design the image and export the result in svg.
Sketch adds various `id` tags to the exported code (note the `id="Page-1"`, `id="My-Star"` and `id="Star-1"` attributes):

```html
<svg width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <g id="My-Star" stroke="#979797" fill="#D8D8D8">
                <polygon id="Star-1" points="11.9860934 18.5835921 5.4876995 22 6.7287823 14.763932 1.47147118 9.63932023 8.73689646 8.58359214 11.9860934 2 15.2352904 8.58359214 22.5007157 9.63932023 17.2434045 14.763932 18.4844873 22 "></polygon>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

I include the svg directly in the html. By doing this, I introduce the same `id` multiple times. Besides the invalid html that is a result of this way of working, I need to style the svg elements based on `id`s. This is a bad practice.

I use css to style the svgs, take a look at an [example](http://codepen.io/petergoes/pen/pybxBL)

**The question:**
Is there a way to replace the `id`s with `class`es when exporting svgs from Sketch? Is there some plugin or setting I can give to the designers?
If not, what is the optimal workflow in receiving svg assets from designers and using it in the page?

Comment: while not ideal, you could use a manual find and replace on the SVG data

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend adding [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) to your workflow if you're dealing with SVGs exported via Sketch. Not only will the tool eliminate unused IDs (you're still on the hook for manually resolving IDs that *are* used by the SVG), it will also optimize the SVG better than the default SVG export.

If you're doing this often, adding SVGO to your dev/build process (see [examples](https://github.com/svg/svgo#other-ways-to-use-svgo)); if you just want to take it for a test run, however, there's also a web-based GUI: https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

Comment: Alternatively, the designers could install the official SVGO plugin for Sketch. https://www.sketch.com/extensions/plugins/svgo-compressor/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no good solution others than asking designers to use ***unique group names***.

The group names  become group ids in the generated SVG.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any solution in Sketch itself, but I found a simple walk-around using PHP. In Sketch, I name each group or path that I want as class starting with a . dot, eg `.person`, and export the file. Obviously the group still has `id=".person"`

And then I load the .svg into page using PHP and replace all IDs that start by a dot by class:

`<?php echo str_replace('id=".', 'class="', file_get_contents( 'sample.svg' )); ?>`

I know it's not ideal but works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a different prefix to the IDs included on each SVG. To avoid glitches, it hides the SVGs until the prefixes are added to the IDs.

CSS:

```css
    svg {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    }
    svg.svg-visible {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

JS:

```js
    function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
      var escapedFind=find.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
      return str.replace(new RegExp(escapedFind, 'g'), replace);
    }
    
    var svgCounter = 0;
    
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('svg'), function(el) {
      var contentReplaced = replaceAll(el.innerHTML,'id="','id="n' + svgCounter); 
      contentReplaced = replaceAll(contentReplaced,'url(#','url(#n' + svgCounter);
      contentReplaced = replaceAll(contentReplaced,'xlink:href="#','xlink:href="#n' + svgCounter);
      el.innerHTML = contentReplaced;
      el.classList.add('svg-visible');
      svgCounter++;
    })
```

You can also make it cleaner using PHP:

```php
    function inlinesvg($module, $svg) {
        $id = 'svg-' . substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) , 0, 8);
        $file_contents = file_get_contents('./assets/img/'.$module.'/'.$svg.'.svg');
        $file_contents = str_replace('id="','id="' . $id, $file_contents);
        $file_contents = str_replace('url(#','url(#' . $id, $file_contents);
        $file_contents = str_replace('xlink:href="#','xlink:href="#' . $id, $file_contents);
        echo $file_contents;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem, so made a plugin. With this plugin, all ids in svg exported from slices are namespaced in BEM style.

https://github.com/Knowre-Dev/svg-namespacing

Comment: Looking at the code of your plugin, you replace the _content_ of the `id` attribute. But the `id` attribute remains in the file. That means that when you have multiple identical svgs in your html document, you end up with multiple occurrences of the same id. I was looking for a way replace the `id` attribute with a `class`attribute, but keep its content. Your plugin did give me a starting point of writing my own plugin. So thank you for that!